# jQuery: jQuery .val() not working in mobile Safari and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have stumbled upon a small problem. I'm trying to post a form using `$.ajax` but it seems that it's not working om moblie Safari or Chrome.

Here's my HTML:

```
<form class="signup-form"  method="POST" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="u" value="03d275307f32a6e64103c71c4">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="5425de82c5">
  <input type="text" class="signup-input email pull-left" 
                     name="EMAIL" placeholder="Enter your email" value="">
  <button class="btn btn-signup">GET EARLY ACCESS</button>
</form> 
<!-- second form -->
<form class="signup-form"  method="POST" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="u" value="03d275307f32a6e64103c71c4">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="5425de82c5">
  <input type="text" class="signup-input email pull-left" 
                     name="EMAIL" placeholder="Enter your email" value="">
  <button class="btn btn-signup">GET EARLY ACCESS</button>
</form>
```

And here's my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var SIGNUP_FORM = $('.signup-form');
var EMAIL_FIELD = $('.email');

SIGNUP_FORM.submit(function() {
  var submitBtn = $(this).children('button');
  submitBtn.text('SENDING...');
  if (EMAIL_FIELD.val().length) {
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    var url = 'MY_URL';
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'GET',
      data: data,
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      success: function(data) {
        submitBtn.text('THANKS!');
      },
      error: function(err) {
        alert("Could not connect to the registration server.");
      }          
    });
  }
  else {
    $(this).children('input').css('border', '1px solid red');
    submitBtn.text('OOOPS');
  }
  return false;
});
});
```

`SIGNUP_FORM = $('.signup-form');` and `EMAIL_FIELD = $('.email');`

Works like it should in all browsers but not mobile Safari or Chrome.

When I try `alert(EMAIL_FIELD.val());` It's empty on mobile but not in desktop browsers.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's above the submit() metod. I've updated the question. @Barmar

Comment: Is the code inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Yes it is. I've update again.

Comment: It works in the browser but not mobile browsers

Comment: There's no `class="email"` anywhere, what is `EMAIL_FIELD` supposed to contain?

Comment: If it's supposed to be the inputs with `name="EMAIL"`, there are two of those fields. `EMAIL_FIELD.val()` will be the value of the first one, even if the user is submitting the second form.

Comment: You've got two `.signup-form` items and two `.email` items. The submit event will be triggered for both forms, but your `EMAIL_FIELD.val()` will always grab from the **first** instance of this class, not necessarily the one in the form you are submitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the eventhandler of the `submit` event of a form, `this` is the form, and uniquely named inputs in the form can be accessed with `this.inputName`.

So in your case instead of `if (EMAIL_FIELD.val().length)` you could say for example `if (this.EMAIL.value !== '')` etc.

At the moment you're selecting all the email-fields from the page and just checking the value length of the first one.